# Set cookie using cURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I’m building a login system in php where I need to use credentials from another website, I’m using an API to login to another server and I’m doing it using cURL. The server where the login credentials are stored does create a cookie with a unique tolken after the user has logged in correctly and this cookie is important to view other webpages and interrogate this pages using other APIs.
This is what I’ve done so far and it seems to work fine, in the login controller php file I’ve got this code

```
$km_username = filter_var($_POST['userName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$km_user_password = $_POST['userPassword'];

$cookieFile = "cookies.txt";
if(!file_exists($cookieFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($cookieFile, "w");
    fwrite($fh, "");
    fclose($fh);
}

$url = 'https://www.apiwebsite.com/api/login.jsp?';

$fields = array(
    'userid' => $km_username,
    'password' => $km_user_password
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In the page where I want to interrogate the server to get other datas I’ve got

```
$dates = array(
    'd_inizio' => '01/01/2017',
    'd_fine' => '31/12/2017'
);

$url = "https://www.apiwebsite.com/api/ricevute.jsp?";
$cookie = "../../km-controllers/cookies.txt";

$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dates));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

So basically after user has logged into the website cURL saves a cookie txt file into my server and this allows me to use that file any other time i want to make another call using for example a different api

Now the question is: what happen if I’ve got more than one user logging into the system? Do I need to create x number of cookies according on how many users log into the system? Would it not be simpler to save the cookie into the user’s browser?

Comment: You could save the cookies in a session variable instead of a file.

Comment: Hi @Barmar I believe this is the answer, do you know how I can save the cookie into a session variable? Also can i pass the session variable into the second curl script to interrogate another page and get the datas? many thanks

Comment: Curl is Server side so `Would it not be simpler to save the cookie into the user’s browser` is not an option as the server knows nothing about the "browser" (or at least doesn't care about it in this context)

Comment: `Now the question is: what happen if I’ve got more than one user logging into the system` it depends on how you access the 3rd party API, if it's sitewide access then no, if the access is based on which user is logged into your system then yes.

Comment: Hi @ArtisticPhoenix thanks for your answer the access is through a login form and the software on the other server does create a token for each use so each user can see different datas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use a different file for each client. What you can do is use `tempnam()` to generate a unique filename for the client, and save this in a session variable, then use it as the cookie jar. The login controller can do this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['cookiefile'])) {
    $cookiefile = tempnam(".", "cookie");
    $_SESSION['cookiefile'] = basename($cookiefile);
}
```

And then the later page can use

```
$cookie = "../../km-controllers/" . $_SESSION['cookiefile'];
```

When the user logs out, you should delete this file and remove the session variable.

There's nothing that will automatically pass the cookies through from the `curl` session to the client browser or vice versa. If you don't want to save the cookies in a file, you can use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_COOKIELIST)` to get the cookies, but you'll then have to parse the info yourself, and later use `CURLOPT_COOKIE` to set each cookie when making future calls. The cookie file automates all this.

Full code for login controller.

```
session_start(); // This needs to be at the very beginning of your script, before anything that produces output
//...
$km_username = filter_var($_POST['userName'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$km_user_password = $_POST['userPassword'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['cookiefile'])) {
    $cookieFile = tempnam(".", "cookie");
    $_SESSION['cookiefile'] = basename($cookiefile);
    file_put_contents($cookieFile, "");
}
$cookieFile = $_SESSION['cookiefile'];


$url = 'https://www.apiwebsite.com/api/login.jsp?';

$fields = array(
    'userid' => $km_username,
    'password' => $km_user_password
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); // Cookie aware
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

And the later interrogator:

```
session_start(); // at very beginning
// ...

$dates = array(
    'd_inizio' => '01/01/2017',
    'd_fine' => '31/12/2017'
);

$url = "https://www.apiwebsite.com/api/ricevute.jsp?";
if (!isset($_SESSION['cookiefile'])) {
    die("no cookie file");
}
$cookie = "../../km-controllers/" . $_SESSION['cookiefile'];

$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($dates));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer I'm going to test it and accept the answer if it worrks. When the user logs out do i need to delete the cookie files as well other than destry the session? Also is this method going to cause issue with the server memory in case of multiple users?

Comment: Yes, you should delete the file when the user logs out.

Comment: Files are on disk, not in memory, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Ok that is perfect. Do I need to create the file as .txt?

Comment: Filename extensions have no special meaning on Unix.

Comment: And `tmpnam()` doesn't let you specify the suffix.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your code to mine but I'm not sure i'm doing it in the right way :( as the file is created but it doesn't contain anything written in it

Comment: I'm not sure why. It should work just the same as before when you use that file as the cookie jar.

Comment: Hi @Barmar is there any chance you could post the entire snipped code with integrated your solution? That would be amazing :) many thanks

Comment: Many thanks so the script creates the file and also the session, but the file is empty, maybe it is because i'm working on localhost? Can it be a permission issue?

Comment: Is the file filled correctly in your original code? It shouldn't matter where the cookie file is located.

Comment: Yes there was a variable error changed $cookieFile with $cookiefile the only error left now is PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Comment: Had the arguments backwards, obviously!

Comment: Perfect it works fine now, just needed to add a / in here $cookie = "../../km-controllers" . $_SESSION['cookiefile']; many th many thnaks for your help and your time